# Check if it's true that $e^{\sin(3.14)} e ^{3.14} \leqslant e^{\sin(3.15)} e ^{3.15} $

Tags: analysis, inequality

Is that true that $e^{\sin(3.14)} e ^{3.14} \leqslant e^{\sin(3.15)} e ^{3.15}$? If yes, does the equality takes place?

I transformated it into:
$\sin(3.14) - \sin(3.15) \leqslant 0.01$.
How to calculate if it's true? I thought about Taylor or Mclaurin, but I need to calculate this without using any calculator.

Comment: I think it should be reverese sign as after pi sin becomes negative

Comment: "If yes, when the equality takes place" **is meaningless** because there are no variables. Please correct it by introducing an intermediate term with a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exponential function is increasing, so it's the same as asking if $3.14 + \sin 3.14 \leq 3.15 + \sin 3.15$. So you want to look at $x + \sin x$ and verify that it's increasing, which can be done by looking at its first derivative and observing that it is nonnegative. The inequality is strict because the derivative is only zero at the one point $x = \pi$ in $[3.14,3.15]$.

Comment: But what is the meaning of all this ? What are we looking for ? I am completely puzzled by the global nonsense of this question and even its answer...

Comment: He's probably asking *if* equality takes place, not when. There are a lot of people on this site for whom English is not a native language

Comment: But the equality of what with what ?

Comment: $3.14 + \sin 3.14$ with $3.15 + \sin 3.15$

Comment: But they are not equal, the first one is 3.14159265..., the second 3.14159275...

Comment: Right, so strict inequality holds here. And this is part of the question he is asking.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the first part,  but (without any agressivity) I would simply be pleased to understand what he means mathematically by "IIf yes, when the equality takes place". I dont think this is a question of mastering English language in a proper way (English is neither my mother's language), and I understand that this "when" may be said for something else like "where", but what is he/she looking for ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Zarrax, of course I meant 'is the equality true' not when/where, that's just a mistake in typing.
Just one more question - whats is the appropiate thesis for fact then when there is only one derivative in [a;b] and the deriavative is non-negative then the function must be strict increasing?

Comment: @Zarrax All right, now I understand... I beg your pardon to you two. I had not seen the part "I am not allowed to use a computational device". I had been completely puzzled by the "when"...

Comment: @piternet You can first show that the function is strictly increasing on $[3.14,\pi]$, and then show the function is strictly increasing on $[\pi, 3.15]$. The relevant theorem is that if the function has positive derivative on the interior of an interval then it is larger at the right endpoint than at the left endpoint. This fact can be proved using the mean value theorem for example.